# Cordova error after Windows reinstallation

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

I'm facing some issue compiling an app in Cordova.
Basically after a Windows re-installation I re-istalled Android Studio, NPM and Cordova but when I try to run an application (I tried with the application I was working on before the OS re-installation and even with the "basic" Cordova app) Cordova give me "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" (rest of the error below).

I've installed Gradle manually "C:\src\gradle-5.6" and set the environment variable (before Windows re-istallation I didn't installed it manually and it was working) and tried even to download and configure via env. varible the same version on the 
\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\ProjectBuilder.js file, which is 4.10.3 but still the same error.

> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
>   ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\william.manzato\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
>   (recommended setting)
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\william.manzato\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
>   (DEPRECATED) Subproject Path: CordovaLib Subproject Path: app
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>   C:\Users\william.manzato\Wamp\NCR Error Codes
>   Translator\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
>   Error output: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

Did anyone else faced this issue and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I reply by myself to this in case someone faces the same issue.

I just downgrade java (JRE and JDK) from 221 to 212, rebooted the pc et voilá, it works again.